# Copy files in folders by groups

Tags: unix

I'm new to coding in Unix. I have a list of files:

```
output_00.txt        
output_01.txt        
output_02.txt          
output_03.txt          
output_04.txt       
output_05.txt         
output_06.txt        
.............          
output_94.txt
```

and a list of 10 folders:

```
output1         
output2        
output3       
output4         
output5     
output6         
output7     
output8        
output9        
output10
```

I would like to copy the files .txt in the folders, so that files from output_00.txt to output_09.txt they will be in the folder "output1", files from output_10.txt to output_19.txt in the folder "output2" and so on. So, the files will be split by groups of 10 in the 10 folders.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) for this:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
   mv output_$((i-1))*.txt output$i/
done
```

Comment: Don't use `seq`. Use `for i in {1..10}` instead.

Comment: `seq` is an external command but `{x..y}` (brace expansion) is a bash built-in and will be more efficient.

Comment: Good! I did not know it. I also read that it is deprecated from bash v3.x+. Thanks for letting me now, I update my answer.